# JQUERY / Javascript - Drag & Resize Pop Up in BLAZOR server App

Tags: javascript, blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side, popupmenu

`I have a component PopUpDemo.razor. Then I have a test.Js file that calls JavaScrip file from wwwroot folder. This JS file is registered in _host.cshtml. When I debug the code it shows no Error but the pop up don't show up.there is no response on page on button click.`

```
@page "/popUpDemo"


<PageTitle>Demo</PageTitle>

<h1>Pop Up demo</h1>

<body>
    <div id="gfg" title="GeeksforGeeks">
        Jquery UI| draggable dialog option
    </div>

    <button id="geeks">Open Dialog</button>
</body>

@code {
    [Inject]
    private IJSRuntime JS { get; set; } = default!;
    private IJSObjectReference? _jsModule;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("setModalDraggableAndResizable");
        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }
}
```

```
function setModalDraggableAndResizable() {
    $('.modal-content').resizable({
        //alsoResize: ".modal-dialog",
        minHeight: 300,
        minWidth: 300
    });
    $('.modal-dialog').draggable();
}
```

```
@page "/"
@namespace Popup_Blazor.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Blazored Modal (demo)</title>
    <base href="~/" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
          rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/test.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <app>
        <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
    </app>
</body>
</html>
```

```
when I click on the button in the Image I want a popup - re-sizable and Drag on the Blazor component.
```

I registered the JS in _host.cshtml and added required JS library references. Also, Injected the JS function in component's page render lifecycle method but it did not worked.

I think, the JS is invoked either before or after my component is rendered. By the time I click the button, JS is not available.  Could anyone explain what I am doing wrong?